# Does TCL have macro like LISP

Tags: tcl

In LISP, one can define a macro, which expands at the same stack level, and not add to the stack. In TCL, one can call a procedure, and then use `uplevel 1`. I have seen it to cause in some instances a significant slow-down. What I would like is a macro-like expansion. Is that available in TCL? I could not find anything to suggest that it does.

Comment: http://wiki.tcl.tk/11156 but there are also different implementations

Answer (score 1):

Macros aren't used that much, since `uplevel`, `upvar` and `tailcall` give a suite of capabilities that do fairly well. In particular, using `uplevel` doesn't prevent bytecode compilation (subject to a few technical restrictions, and providing you're using 8.6 or later) so you can go ahead and use that without worrying too much. Which isn't to say that macros can't be done, but they're done by introducing on the outside a command that creates commands (probably procedures) that have had macro expansion performed on them during their definition. Once you work that way, you can do quite radical rearrangements of the code; the input text does not need to look like Tcl at all.

There are a few pages on the Tcler's Wiki on the topic; http://wiki.tcl.tk/3888, http://wiki.tcl.tk/11156, etc. A sort-of macro system I've written and that I'm using live is embedded within [tclquadcode](https://core.tcl.tk/tclquadcode/artifact/9178df0f77365f49?ln=2349,2437). With that, I'm able to use pseudo-assembly basic block labels as macro-like things: that involves not just a simple replacement, but rather relocating the code concerned to the beginning of the script body so that I don't need to manually declare the variables concerned up front (which I'd previously found to be horribly error-prone and hard to read); it's internally using lambda terms rather than procedures for scoping control, but the difference isn't too important here given that `label` is the macro, not `build`. [Here's an example of use of that code](https://core.tcl.tk/tclquadcode/artifact/07a7de62de8a2337?ln=218,233). The relevant bit of that code is (if I do typical replacements for readability):

```
build {
    my condBr [my and [my isNumericInt $x] [my isNumericInt $y]] \
        $ints $doubles
label ints:
    my ret [my add(INT,INT) [my numeric.int $x] [my numeric.int $y]]
label doubles:
    set left [my cast(DOUBLE) $x "left"]
    set right [my cast(DOUBLE) $y "right"]
    my ret [my add(DOUBLE,DOUBLE) $left $right]
}
```

That's internally rewritten quite a bit, to approximately this:

```
apply {{func x y} {
    set ints [$func block "ints"]
    set doubles [$func block "doubles"]
    my SetCurrentBasicBlock [$func getEntryBlock]

    my condBr [my and [my isNumericInt $x] [my isNumericInt $y]] \
        $ints $doubles

    my SetCurrentBasicBlock $ints

    my ret [my add(INT,INT) [my numeric.int $x] [my numeric.int $y]]

    my SetCurrentBasicBlock $doubles

    set left [my cast(DOUBLE) $x "left"]
    set right [my cast(DOUBLE) $y "right"]
    my ret [my add(DOUBLE,DOUBLE) $left $right]
}} $func $x $y
```

Very approximately. The real version of the generated code is a *lot* more complex because of debugging metadata tracking; this is pretty hefty code generation under the hood.

Comment: My code is using `regexp` pretty heftily. Other macro systems use other approaches. Also, this is macro-like stuff to keep the code simple, not to accelerate performance. (It's ultimately going to generate machine code so there's performance as an end goal, but it is an immediate non-goal in the code I presented simply because each call to `build` is a one-off.)

Comment: Thanks, I have used uplevel (not sure if it was 8.5, or 8.5), and it slowed me down. What I did was my version of variable command. Is this stopping the byte code optimizations? See proc code below (sorry, I can't get the newlines and code highlight mode to work):
    
proc rvariable { var_name } { uplevel 1 [ list variable $var_name ; set $var_name ]
}